# Segmentation fault on QPixmap::load

Tags: qt, load, segmentation-fault, qpixmap

This is the code:

```
void MainWindow::setPic(QString loc, int panel)
{
    if(panel == 1)
    {
        loc1 = loc;
        QPixmap pmap;
        facedetect(loc1.toStdString(), 1, "CAND1.jpg");
        qDebug() << "Loading : " << loc1;
        pmap.load(loc1); // I'm getting the segfault error in this line
        qDebug() << "Loaded : " << loc1;
        ui->PicView1->setPixmap(pmap);
    }

}
```

How could I resolve this error?

BTW, I'm using Qt 4.8 with the latest Qt Creator, on Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried it with wallpapers, it crashes. I tried it with my 1x1 id pic, crashed (how rude...), I tried it with a strip of my examination schedule (cropped from a different image), it said it loaded, but the `QLabel` `PicView1` doesn't display anything.

I tried declaring the `QPixmap` as global variable, got segfault.

Comment: Filling a null pixmap doesn't make much sense, and there is no reason for the code you posted to fail, problem likely is elsewhere. Are you certain that `loc` thing is indeed a valid, live QString?

Comment: Yes, I was assured that it has contents, the Debug view of Qt Creator said it has.

Comment: Even an invalid path must not crash QPixmap. Try with different image files to make sure its not a bug in the image reading code.

Comment: I tried it with wallpapers, it crashes. I tried it with my 1x1 id pic, crashed (how rude...), I tried it with a strip of my examination schedule (cropped from a different image), it said it loaded, but the `QLabel PicView1` doesn't display anything.

Comment: this also happened to me !! how did you sovle this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't fill you image with white before loading...
Use QPixmap hence :

```
QString loc;
// fill loc with a path to your image file.
QPixmap pmap;
pmap.load(loc);
```

Be carefull, all image type can't be read with QT. Look here [QtImageReading](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#reading-and-writing-image-files) to see the datatype supported by QT.

Comment: An unsupported image type shouldn't raise a segfault, it would just make `load` return false. (Now a _corrupted_ image file could potentially uncover bugs in the image decoder. Seems like a stretch though.)

Comment: I tried `loc1 = loc;` then used `pmap.load(loc1);` still gives segfault. The image is of `.jpeg` format.

Comment: Does your imge is opennable with a third part software like gimp, eog or ms paint ? As rek said, maybe your image is corrupted. Do you want to send me your image, i can try to load it in a qpixmap

Comment: Ok, could you please post me the result of qDebug() << loc1.
are you absolutly sure that the segfault occurs durring the load ?
I Just try the following code on my computer, and all is fine :

`QString loc("./toto.jpg");
QString loc1 = loc;
QPixmap pmap;
qDebug() << "Loading : " << loc1;
pmap.load(loc1);
qDebug() << "Loaded : " << loc1;`

Comment: How big is your image ? Could you send it to me ?

Comment: I unmodified the code, here's output: Loading :  "./toto.jpg" 
Loaded :  "./toto.jpg" the image I'm trying to use is in here : http://i.imgur.com/yG3bP.jpg

Comment: I haven't any segfault when loading this image with the code I wrote in the previous comment.